# DateTime value is not sending back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cant seem to find the problem here. Really stuck and need help. Im using Html.BeginForm and inside i have editorFor - model.DOB. Used post method but somehow it doesnt send the property back to my controller. Do help. I have other string property fields which is sending fine to the controller. Only date property not sending. TQVM in advance.

---------Edit---------

Just found out that if i use Edge - i need to use dd/MM/yyyy format. Then it will saves fine. If i use MM/dd/yyyy, then it will give null on the controller.

On chrome

using dd/MM/yyyy - gives me 'The field must be a date' error

using MM/dd/yyyy - gives me null.

---------Edit---------

Model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public DateTime? PersonDOB { get; set; }
```

View

```
@model Models.CorporationModel
using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonDOB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonDOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Format: 06/31/1998" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonDOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="action:PersonalSave" />
                <input type="submit" value="Reprocess" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" name="action:PersonalReprocess" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "PersonalReprocess")]
public ActionResult PersonalReprocess(int id, CorporationModel corporationModel, HttpPostedFileBase postedResultFile, HttpPostedFileBase postedPersonalFile)
{
    corporationModel.Verified = "Processing";
    return UpdatePersonal(id, corporationModel, postedResultFile, postedPersonalFile);
}
```

If i remove the

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Im getting the 'The field must be a date error'. If i switch between month and date manually, then it saves without problem. However, when it pulls from the db, it will start with dd/mm/yyyy and then clicking on save will gives out 'the field must be a date error' again, so need to switch it manually.

Comment: Hit F12 > Network and press submit. Verify if the PersonDOB parameter is listed in the post parameters

Comment: @OleEHDufour hi. Just found out that if i save the DOB as dd/mm/yyyy then it saves fine. But if i use mm/dd/yyyy it will be null. But i specify in the model '[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]'. Any idea?

Comment: Try use DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy} and change windows short date format to dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @JackSparrow Hi. just updated the question. i found out the problem depends on the browser also.

Comment: @JackSparrow this will only work in *some* countries. That's not a solution

Comment: @ArifSam *don't* try to hard-code the date format. It will always fail for some countries. *Don't* send localized date strings from the browser, use the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD...`. MVC will recognize it without specifying anything in `DisplayFormat`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi. I removed the format from the model and tested on both edge and chrome. On edge. if i use dd/mm/yy - its ok. mm/dd/yy - null value. On chrome. dd/mm/yy - 'The field must be a date' error. mm/dd/yy - null value.

Comment: @ArifSam don't send localized dates. Use the ISO8601 format. Use a datepicker control on the server if you want. Otherwise make sure you set the *CultureInfo* for the site or the request to the one you want. You can set it for the entire site from web.config, for specific pages or based eg on the end user's preference. This is explained in [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thx. you could put it as answer and ill accept. managed to do it by placing auto globalization in web.config. Just a question, ive tested with chrome and edge. Both of it has different culture. Is there a way to specify single culture which could be handled automatically so that the user doesnt need to key in different format of date depending on browser?